# How to stop puppeteer from overwriting duplicate?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have to write a program as a schoolproject which automaticly screenshots the gasprices from 10 locations for 2 months . I used puppeteer and it works. However if i start it again it overwrites the files because they have the same name. I locked for solutions but couldnt find something that works. Does someone know a solution.

```
    const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
    async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080}
    });                                                                                           
    await page.goto("https://spritpreisalarm.de")    
   
    await page.type("#searchform > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=text]","Leipzig");
    await page.click("#searchform > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > input");
    
   
    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/7450/LEIPZIG/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path:"Leipzig/totalLE.png"});
    
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise')
  
    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/8731/LEIPZIG/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path:"Leipzig/ARALMstr.png"});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise');
 
    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/7977/LEIPZIG/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path:"Leipzig/ARALMaxistr.png"});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise');
 
    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/15601/LEIPZIG/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path:"Leipzig/JETrustr.png"});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise');
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de');

    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/13865/04683/1/5' , {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path:"Naunhof/STARbrandisstr.png"});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise');
    
    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/1893/BERLIN/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await page.screenshot({path:"Berlin/ARALHolzmarktstr.png"});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de');
      
    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/3091/BERLIN/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await page.screenshot({path:"Berlin/TotalHolzmarkstr.png"});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise');

    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/5045/GRIMMA/1/5', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path:"Grimma/AutobahntankstelleGrimma.png"})
    
    await browser.close()
}
start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply add the date to the file name so you can do two actions in one ;p.

- have the date
- no overwriting

```js
let date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)
    await page.screenshot({path: screensDir + `/${date}ARALMstr.png`});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise');
```

I didn't run it, but you understand the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it worked. Is there any way to add hours to the date?

Comment: yes you can even add the minutes play with slicing the new Data()

Comment: Is it normal that if you typ slice(0,14) it changes the png file into a normal file?

Comment: You can slice and play with it however you feel but the idea Is the same

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to create a new subfolder for your screenshots every time u start the script. Use a unique name for that for example the current timestamp:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const currentDate = new Date();
const timestamp = currentDate.getTime()+'';
const screensDir = path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, timestamp, 'Leipzig'));

if (!fs.existsSync(screensDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(screensDir, {recursive: true});
}

async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080}
    });
    
    page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://spritpreisalarm.de")    

    await page.type("#searchform > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=text]","Leipzig");
    await page.click("#searchform > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > input");


    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/7450/LEIPZIG/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path: screensDir + '/totalLE.png'});

    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise')

    await page.goto('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise/station/8731/LEIPZIG/1/1', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.screenshot({path: screensDir + '/ARALMstr.png'});
    await page.goBack('https://spritpreisalarm.de/preise');
    
    //...
    
    await browser.close()
}
start()
```